# El Capitan PHP Cross-Site Folder/File Access

Tags: php, reference, osx-elcapitan, cross-site

QUESTION:  What must be done to access the folders and files of other sites from the current site when all sites are contained within the same Sites folder.

CONSTRAINT:  Any change that is made should be performed on the fly.  I do not wish to permanently disrupt the security of my system.  I want only to be able to cross-reference folders and files when the need arises.

BACKGROUND: I have no trouble accessing the files and folders within the same site, but am unable to access those in the folders of other sites.

SAMPLE OF DILEMMA:

```
Current Location: /Users/username/Sites/samplesite1.com/myFile.php

$pathname = '../../samplesite2.com/samplefile.html;
var_dump(file_exists($pathname));  // boolean(false)

Browser Address: http://localhost/~username/samplesite1.com/myFile.php
```

Comment: That would look like one too many ../

Comment: The samplesite1 and -2 folders are both in the Sites folder.  If I go up only one I will still be in the samplesite1 folder.   I only wish that it were a simple path problem.  Thanks, anyway.

Comment: Not based on your example. You're in samplesite1.com, parent of which is already the Sites. But if you have tried then there is something else wrong still

Comment: But, you happen to be right, and thankfully, I am in error.